# How to stop listening to for core window character received event?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a `Page` in which I have registered `CharacterReceived` event as below:

```
 Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
```

Also on the same page, there's a usercontrol which acts as a popup windows. In that user control I have another key handling event as below:

```
 Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += PageCoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
```

Now when this flyout is open and any key is pressed both the event's is getting fired. Is there any way to disable parent's `CharacterReceived` event and than enable it again.

I know it can be achieved by unregistering `CharacterReceived` event when flyout is open and register again when flyout is closed, but to do that I have to do some workaround for complex logic. I want to unregister `CharacterReceived` from the `UserControl` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events themselves are different. If you used `AcceleratorKeyActivated` in both places for example, you could use the `AcceleratorKeyEventArgs.Handled` property to stop the event propagation once it was handled in the `UserControl`.

If that is not an option for you, you could solve the problem by exposing some method on your page, that will start and stop observing the events:

```
public void StartObserving() => 
   Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;

public void StopObserving() =>
   Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived -= CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
```

Now you can call these methods from your user control when appropriate. To get the instance of currently displayed page, you could use the `Window.Current` property:

```
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; //if your window contains a frame on top
var page = rootFrame.Content as MyPageType; //where MyPageType is the type of your page
page.StopObserving();
```